# How to prevent losing transparency when pasting an image

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard, gimp, image-editing

I noticed that when I paste a transparent image like this [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX1Jg.png) in GIMP, it loses it's trasparency and is given a black background. Is there any way to disable that behaviour or at least prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me, with:

- clicking on your image in Firefox or Chrome, to open it on another tab,
- right click the image and `Copy image`
- in Gimp, either:

  - `File>Create>From clipboard`
  - `Edit>Paste`

  that both create an image/layer with a transparent background

So, for me Gimp works and if you get a non-transparent image it is because your browser (IE?) isn't passing the alpha channel correctly. Did you try to paste in another application and if so do you get the transparency there?